# VS2015 C++ cross-platform for iOS, vcremote issues

Tags: c++, ios, visual-studio-2015

I have installed all the prerequisites for using VS2015 to build, deploy and debug an iOS app ( currently just trying with the samples that comes with VS2015 )

Everything works fine, it builds and deploys the test-app to my iPad, but once it's supposed to start it, it fails with:

**Unable to start debugging. Unexpected LLDB output from command "-target-select remote localhost:3031". Command 'target-select'. Fn 'target-select' failed**

Tried to google this but the information / support for this seems to be minimal to nonexistant.

If I launch the app manually on the iPad it runs just fine.